# Is there a good way to say that if char array contains null then do something?

Tags: c

I've been trying to find a good way to find the end of a partially filled char array. What I've been trying is if array[x] != null, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Unless you have the maximum size of the array (i.e. the number of elements it contains) then there's no safe way to do this. Otherwise, just loop over it and check for a `0` (or `'\0'` which is the same thing).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What if I do know the maximum size of the array?

Comment: By the way, you say "*partially filled*"... What do you mean by that? Like e.g. `array[0]` and `array[3]` is initialized, but not `array[1]` or `array[2]`? Then depending on when, where and how the array was defined and created, the uninitialized elements might be just that, *uninitialized*. That means their values will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. That means you can't loop over the array and check for zero, you need to *know* which elements have been initialized, and can only check them.

Comment: Also, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: So like I'm filling from the bottom up, but its possible it doesn't get completely filled, so like array[0] through array[2] are filled but array[3] wouldn't be filled.

Comment: In that case it's easy, loop from index 0 to index 2 (inclusive) and just check if the element at the current index is zero.

Comment: Lastly, I think you should take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You say that it "doesn't seem to be working". But ***how*** doesn't it seem to be working? Do you get build errors or warnings? Crashes when running? Unexpected results or output? Please elaborate.

Comment: If you know the max size as you claimed in the comment, what is wrong with looping?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strlen` to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // strlen

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    char str_array[32];
    strcpy (str_array, "I am short");
    printf ("string length: %d\n", strlen(str_array));
    printf ("last index: %d\n", str_array[strlen(str_array)]);
    return 0;
}
```

This should return

```
string length: 10
last index: 0
```

Notice that `strlen ()` returned the length of the string stored in the array which is also the index of the NULL ('\0') terminator.

Comment: What if the character array doesn't have the null terminator at all?

Comment: @VHS the array will be initialized with zeros which means that if the string is shorter than the array length there will always be at least one null character

Answer (score 0):

If your char array is null terminated, checking for the first null should work. If it isn't, you're doing something wrong.
In practice, there needs to be a char that determines the end of your char array, otherwise it's impossible to tell where it ends, unless you consider the length of the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   int i ;
   char array[64] ;

   for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
      array[i] = 'a' ;

   array[5] = '\0' ;

   for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
   {
      if (array[i+1] == '\0')
         break ;
   }

   printf ("the filled string ends after %d characters.\n", i-1) ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Why `array[i+1]`? With that loop you have the possibility to go out of bounds with that.

Comment: and if the first character is the null character you will miss it

Answer (score 0):

How about the following way?

```
int i=0
char array[30];
fillArray(&array); //some function that writes characters to this array
for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
   if(array[i] == '\0') {
       printf("Char array is a string\n");
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: See [strnlen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strnlen.3.html), which is in Posix and widely available in C library implementations. Appending K of the C standard defines the optional interface `strnlen_s` with roughly the same interface (the difference is that `strnlen_s` returns 0 if given a NULL string pointer, instead of being undefined behaviour).

Comment: How do you pass an array with its size?!